# PositionChanged event gives the old location details when application is restarted

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I have the below code which works fine except that it gives the last location details it tracked when application is restarted.

And it gives the correct location details after I click on btnGetLocationDetails button 2 or 3 times.
Any idea how I can fix this issue so that every time app is launched user doesn't need to click on this button 2 or 3 times to get the correct current location?

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = null; 
    Location location=null;

    private void btnGetLocationDetails_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Granted)
        {
            watcher.MovementThreshold = Convert.ToDouble("100");
        }
        watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>(watcher_PositionChanged);

        //   PositionChanged events occur whenever your position changes     
        watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_OnStatusChanged);
        watcher.Start();
   }

   void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
   {
        //get the coordinates
        location = new Location();
        location.Latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        location.Longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
        location.Altitude = e.Position.Location.Altitude;
   }


   void watcher_OnStatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
   {            
        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled)
           MessageBox.Show("The location service is turned off.");
        else if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.NoData)
     MessageBox.Show("No location data is available. ");
   }       
 }
```

Comment: Not sure about the behaviour you're seeing. Side-note from the WP8 aspect: If you're trying to do one-time geolocation acquisition it's much better to use WP8's Geolocator over WP7's GeoCoordinateWatcher. "var geoLoc = await new Geolocator().GetGeopositionAsync();"

Comment: Justin, I am getting inconsitent behavior with GetGeopositionAsync. Sometimes it never returns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080600/getgeopositionasync-drives-me-nuts  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/ff166fac-b423-4428-abd8-610bf0102fc0