# GetGeopositionAsync does not return

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 app, I am trying to use GetGeopositionAsync on the main page to display some items based on user location.

Calling GetGeopositionAsync does not return within the specified timeout, it doesn't return at all.

The code I am using is simple:

```
            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

            Geoposition geoposition = null;
            try
            {
                geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                    maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
           {

                // location services disabled or other error
                // user should setup his location

            }
```

The solution I was able to find was to create an async wrapper for GeoCoordinateWatcher which seems to be working fine.
But I am not too confident in my solution, I would prefer to use GetGeopositionAsync which looks like the recommended way of getting device position in WP8.

UPDATE: other people are reporting same behavior:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/ff166fac-b423-4428-abd8-610bf0102fc0

Comment: A variable named 'IsBusy' is always a good way to create deadlock.  We can't see where else you use it.

Comment: please ignore that. I put breakpoints just after the await and in the catch clause, and neither are reached

Comment: Do you call `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack?

Answer (score 5):

When are you calling the method to request the geoposition? I found I encountered the same issue when I made the call part of the constructor in my ViewModel.

I was able to fix the problem in my code by adding an OnLoadedCommand and calling the method from there. I've had no further issues since.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I came up with and it fixed my issue completely.

Comment: Calling from page.Loaded event fixed the problem for me too. Before I used to call in VM constructor.

Answer (score 4):

This is strange but GetGeoPositionAsync only returns the current position when the Geolocator is initialized with either MovementThreshold and/or ReportInterval.

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
geolocator.MovementThreshold = 5;
geolocator.ReportInterval = 500;

Geoposition geoposition = null;
try
{
    geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
        maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    // location services disabled or other error
    // user should setup his location
}
```

Comment: this is the solution!!

Comment: To get it wokring I only set these two geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 2; geolocator.MovementThreshold = 3;   Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when testing on a Device.  I had to disable the WiFi on the device in order to get it to work. I know that some people have had the opposite problem working on the emulator. I did not have to do any wrapping. Hope it Helps

Answer (score 1):

I found one thing. If I set accuracy to bigger one then geolocator starts return coordinates. So it dosen't work for 50 meters but works for 500 so try to use the line below instead.

```
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some of the same issues above.  When I hooked up to the geolocator.StatusChanged event, I noticed that sequence of events was:

1. StatusChanged -> Initializing
2. My await call
3. StatusChanged -> Ready

So I added a loop before my await call:

```
  while (geolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Initializing)
  {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
```

This is inelegant, but did work.

Answer (score 0):

This weird behaviour happens when the status of `geolocator` is in `NotInitialized` state while calling the `GetGeopositionAsync()`.

The `geolocator` is only `Ready` in two cases. One, when it is subscribed to a `PositionChanged` event. Two, when a `GetGeopositionAsync()` is called already.

So, you just have to subscribe the `geolocator` to a `positionChanged` event before calling the `GetGeopositionAsync()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you created the Geolocator locally, the task will end up being cancelled.  It works when I created a permanent Geolocator instance.

Answer (score 0):

See my sample:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-Cimbalino-3888977e

it uses MVVM & Cimbalino Toolkit!

In my case I set ReportInterval = 5 to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like everyone hacked away until it worked... Here's what worked for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// HACK: For some reason Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync hangs indefinitely.
/// The workaround is to add a PositionChanged handler.
/// </summary>
private Geoposition GetGeoposition()
{
    var geolocator = new Geolocator();
    var semaphoreHeldUntilPositionReady = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 0);
    Geoposition position = null;

    geolocator.ReportInterval = 1000;
    geolocator.PositionChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        position = args.Position;
        semaphoreHeldUntilPositionReady.Release();
    };

    semaphoreHeldUntilPositionReady.Wait();
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this is a bit older, but I hope that others searching for this topic find this answer helpful.

Make sure to get the user's consent before attempting to access the location services.

I was running into this problem but fixed it by calling the OnNavigatedTo event when opening the page to get their consent.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent"))
    {
        // User has opted in or out of Location
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = 
            MessageBox.Show("This app accesses your phone's location. Is that ok?", 
            "Location",
            MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = true;
        }else
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["LocationConsent"] = false;
        }

        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote because your answer doesn't have anything to do with the OP.  Your app will fail certification, but consent has nothing to do with geolocation/geoposition working or not.