# GetGeopositionAsync takes too long to complete

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps, geolocation, location

current I use this code to get GPS:

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default;
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
try
{
    Geoposition currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(currentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, currentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("This operation returned because the timeout period expired."))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("GPS is taking too long too complete. Pleaes try again.");
        this.SetProgressIndicator(false);
        RadBusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        return;
    }
    else
    {                           
        this.SetProgressIndicator(false);
        RadBusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        return;
    }
};
```

But it always takes too long to complete, as you can see I set timeout 30s but not sure why
it doesn't show timeout exception when took more than 30s.
I'm getting stuck on this issue. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What *is* happening for you?

Comment: @RowlandShaw a hundred of device is using my app with these code that get GPS but 10% of them warn me that it takes too long to get GPS although I set timeout for it (30s).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the wifi or cellphone device is on, this enables the fallback methods to be used when the GPS device can't find a signal.

Someone with more or less the same problem made another thread in here:
[GetGeopositionAsync does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080600/getgeopositionasync-does-not-return)

More information on the GeoLocator class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator#properties

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why too, but `TimeSpan`is realy slow, but doing it with `ReportInterval` works fine:

```
geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
geolocator.ReportInterval = 2000;
geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;

private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
try
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        myPosition = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
    });
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Data == null) throw;
    else MessageBox.Show("Exception while Tracking: " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
}
}
```